# Getting the values on the database and put it into an array without key,

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having a problem retrieving the value from the database and put it into an array, I'm creating round robin scheduling system, for which the teams is stored into the database, the problem is on how can I retrieve those values and put it into the array,

Here's my piece of code on the sql;

```
$db_result = mysql_query("SELECT teams FROM game");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($db_result, MYSQL_NUM);
$read = $row[0];
```

And I want to put those values into this array:

```
$team = array ();
```

By the way I used to save to this method into a single row on the database(example data only):

```
john,ken,mary,ben,mike
```

Comment: Glad you don't do that any more!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:
In the end $team will be an array of the values in the "teams" column.
You can get extra info here: [mysql_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)

Edit(added mysqli version because mysql_query is deprecated):

```
<?php 
$sql = "SELECT teams FROM game"; 
$teams = array();
    if ($db_result = $mysqli->query($sql)) { 
        while($obj = $db_result->fetch_assoc()){ 
            $teams[] = $obj['teams'];
        } 
    } 
    $result->close();         
?>
```

to pass the data as a string parameter to an array the php [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) can be used:

```
$colleges = array(implode(",", $teams));
```

Comment: You'd better use the msqli extension, the mysql extension is deprecated.

Comment: @LorenzMeyer your comment is correct, [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) is the way to do it because mysql_query is deprecated, but the user tried to use mysql_query, I've corrected he's code, a mysqli version would be a plus

Comment: thank you, but how can I get those exact values from the teams column, and put those value in the array ,

Comment: @BenP.H I don't undertand what data needs to be in which array

Comment: let's try to change the variable on the $team = array(), instead of "team" I'll just say lets use "$college = array()", what I mean is how can I get the exact value of teams from the database and put those values on "$college = array()", like this "$college =  array ('john,ken,mary,ben,mike');" thank you :)

Comment: @BenP.H is "john,ken,mary,ben,mike" values from the "teams" column? would it fix the issue formating "john,ken,mary,ben,mike" as string and then pass it to the $college array?

Comment: @BenP.H: check last 2 rows of answer; do it by using the implode function